# Predict a data using Pickle file

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, pickle, data-science-experience

I have pre build machine learning model (saved as pickle file) to predict classification.

My question is when I use new dataset to predict using Pickle file do I need do all preprocessing steps (like transformation and encoding) to the new testing dataset or can I use raw data set.

Comment: It depends on whether the model does preprocess inside its predict function or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You will have to perform all the preprocessing on the test dataset as well. Such as scaling, one hot encoding etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).